# illegal instruction: opcode with wrong RegOpcode value

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-code, opcode

i am writing a x86 disassembler and i realized that when executing the instruction `MOV reg16, segmentReg` (opcode 0x8C) with the field RegOpcode from ModRM greater than 5, it will throw an exception illegal instruction, this make sence since there are no more than 6 segment registers.

**so my question is:** where intel specifies this behavior? i am reading the intel manuals but I can not find any information about this.

**and since i am writing a disassembler:** is there any "standard" way to know when the opcode may throw an ilegal instruction if any operand is wrong, or should i add conditions for these opcodes in my code? something like this:

```
if(opcode == 0x8C)
    if(ModRM.RegOpcode > 5)
        return wrong_operand
    endif
endif
// all fine
```

Comment: Interesting.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov#real-address-mode-exceptions (and other sections) only mentions `#UD` on attempting to load CS (which may have been legal on some 8086 CPU?), not for other encodings which don't even specify a segment reg.  AFAIK, those encodings haven't yet been overloaded to mean something completely different, the way VEX prefixes overlap with invalid LDS / LES encodings.  (I wonder if that possibility of future expansion is an intentional reason for Intel *not* to specify `#UD`... no, `les` specifies #UD on non-memory.)

Comment: Perhaps worth checking AMD's manuals to see if they specify the behaviour anywhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes another one is `POP m16/32` (opcode 0x8F) if RegOpcode is any other value than zero, it will throw an exception. I really would like to find any official information about this

Comment: I would assume there's a catchall somewhere in the manual saying something like "all encodings not explicitly defined are reserved for future use and their behavior is undefined."

Comment: It’s not as clearly specified as one might like. Regarding segment register encodings, section B.1.4.5 says “Do not use reserved encodings”, but it doesn’t say they cause #UD. Possibly because they don’t on some implementations.

Comment: Regarding opcode 8F, section A.4.2 says “All blanks in the opcode maps are reserved and must not be used. Do not depend on the operation”. So it’s not specified as causing #UD, but as undefined behavior, for which #UD is one possible implementation. (Exactly as @Nate speculated.)

Comment: @prl where in intel manuals says this quote? i could not find it

Comment: In SDM volume 2 sections A.4.2 and B.1.4.5, in footnotes below the tables.

Comment: @prl indded it is, i cannot believe there is so much important information in appendix.